# create generic data table using angular material

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, columnsorting, angular-material-table

I want to create reusable angular material data table which can be used by any component and need to pass only required column header and other table data. Below is what I tried:

I am following this example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resuable-datatable-higlkc)

Created `shared` folder in `src/app` folder. and data table component too which will be reusable.

**data-table.component.html:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of objectKeys(columnHeader)">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{columnHeader[tableData]}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index;"> {{element[tableData]}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="objectKeys(columnHeader)"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: objectKeys(columnHeader);"></tr>
</table>
```

**data-table.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tableData;
  @Input() columnHeader;
  @Input() source;
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.tableData);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Now I am using `app-data-table` selector where I want. I have profile component in which I want to use this.

**profile-setup.component.html:**

```
<app-data-table [tableData]="tableData" [columnHeader]="columnHeader"></app-data-table>
```

**profile-setup.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileSetUp } from 'src/app/_interface/profile-setup.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-setup',
  templateUrl: './profile-setup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-setup.component.scss']
})


export class ProfileSetupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  columnHeader = {'profileName': 'Profile Name', 'profileDesc': 'Description', 'adminUser': 'Admin User', 'id': ''};

  tableData: ProfileSetUp[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      profileName: "Cameron Villams",
      profileDesc: "Face to face contact",
      adminUser: "Iwan Rynders",
      action: ""
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      profileName: "Charl Angle",
      profileDesc: "Face to face contact",
      adminUser: "Unknown",
      action: ""
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      profileName: "Johan Abraham",
      profileDesc: "Face to face contact",
      adminUser: "Unknown",
      action: ""
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      profileName: "Niekie Gadgilly",
      profileDesc: "Face to face contact",
      adminUser: "Unknown",
      action: ""
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      profileName: "Veer S",
      profileDesc: "Face to face contact",
      adminUser: "Unknown",
      action: ""
    }
  ];    
}
```

**profile-setup.module:**

```
export interface ProfileSetUp {
    id: number;
    profileName: string;
    profileDesc: string;
    adminUser: string;
    action: string;
}
```

How can I **show data conditionally** like, some of the data-tables may have "Edit", "Delete" buttons, some of the don't have those buttons. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for this?

Comment: @Ininiv this is what I had referred: https://stackblitz.com/edit/resuable-datatable-higlkc

Comment: @Ininiv did you get that?

Comment: @Ininiv hey, can you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to pass a callback function to the table component. (updated project: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resuable-datatable-ztrnnk))

**DataTableComponent**

add an input for the button and a call for it.

```
  @Input() editButton;

  onEdit(element) {
    this.editButton(element);
  }
```

**data-table.component.html**

add logic to add a button for edit wiring the callback.

```
<div *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] != 'Edit'">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[tableData] }}</td>
</div>
<div *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] == 'Edit'">
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <button mat-button (click)="onEdit(element)">
        edit
      </button> 
  </td>
</div>
```

**EmployeeComponent**

add an edit column.

```
columnHeader = {'studentID': 'ID', 'fname': 'First Name', 'lname': 'Last Name', 'weight': 'Weight', 'symbol': 'Code', 'edit': 'Edit'};
```

create a method for the callback.

```
  onEditClick = (element) => this.onEdit(element);

  onEdit(element) {
    console.log(element);
  }
```

**employee.component.html**

```
<app-data-table [tableData]="tableData" [columnHeader]="columnHeader" [editButton]="onEditClick"></app-data-table>
```